# Switching math fonts under xelatex (range options vs combo fonts)

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I know this is a common problem: in `xelatex` I need to switch both text and math fonts from serif to sans and back. Here is my setup, based on `unicode-math`:

```
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[BoldItalicFont={Adobe Garamond Pro Bold Italic},
         Ligatures=TeX]{SimonciniGaramondStd}
\setsansfont[BoldFont={Roboto Medium},Scale=MatchUppercase]{Roboto}
\newcommand{\mathstd}{%
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={5,7,9}]%
\setmathfont[range=it/{Latin,latin}]{SimonciniGaramondStd-Italic}%
\setmathfont[range=it/{Greek,greek},Scale=.9]{Gentium Plus Italic}%
```

Notice that my main math font combines Garamond-math with Simonicini Garamond for latin italic with and Gentium for greek italic letters.
In order to switch to the sans math font I might define a new math version:

```
\setmathfont[version=sansserif]{Noto Sans Math}
```

however, it is known that `version` and `range` options cannot work together, and I really need to substitute for the italic letters in my main math font.

I would like to know if there is a way out. I remember some time ago someone mentioned the possibility of creating a combo font as an alternative to `range`, but I have no idea if this is possible in xelatex and how to do it.

Comment: Did you fix the issue?