# Make a command within an environment have persisting effects

Tags: environments

Maybe this is trivial, but what I am trying to do is to define a command at the end of an environment so that it affects the text after the environment. Consider the following example:

```
\newenvironment{italic}{\it}{\bf}

\begin{italic}
This is italic.
\end{italic}
This should be boldface!
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the command `\bf` affect the text after the environment?

Remark: Of course my problem is not to change from italic to boldface. What I need to do  is to change the fonts locally inside an environment with `\setmathfont` (under XeLaTeX). Unfortunately, in this case, the change made within the environment is not local, so I have to restore the main font setting at the end of the environment.

Comment: you should not use `\bf` or `\it` (which are not defined by default) but `\aftergroup\bf` does what you ask

Comment: It's much better if you explain your *real* problem. I don't get why the font change inside the environment should have global effects. Maybe you want to define a math version for usage in the environment?

Comment: Yes, but I know that problem has no solution at the moment, as `unicode-math` does not allow to use `version` and `range` at the same time. This is why I looked for a workaround, but I found the problem above. In fact, the problem is that when I change the math font inside the environment with `\setmathfont`, the change is global, this is why I want to revert to the standard font at the end of the environment. In any case, I think my question is relevant in itself, and the answer has been provided by David Carlisle pointing to the command `\aftergroup`

Comment: Namely, the ultimate reason of my problem is that when I change the math font inside the environment with `\setmathfont`, the change is global, so I need to to explicitly revert to the standard font at the end of the environment.

Comment: It seems to me that you should be asking a different question related to your 3 hours ago comment.

Comment: You mean that I should ask ALSO a question about `\setmathfont`? What I needed to know is how we set a command within an environment that affects the text after the environment. This is a stand alone question, for which I had a reply, and it is far more general than the issue related to `unicode-math`.
BTW, I already askes about font math switching some time ago, but unfortunately I got no answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655766/54334